# Multicast Block: How to generalize

Tags: objective-c, delegates, objective-c-blocks, nsinvocation, multicastdelegate

**Goal**

I have a class with various properties that can be used to plug in a block to receive certain events.

```
@interface SomeClass

@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^handler)(int arg1, int arg2);

@end
```

In the client code, I would like to dynamically add / remove handler blocks to this property, similar to a MulticastDelegate in C#.

```
self.logger = ^(int arg1, int arg2){
    NSLog(@"arg1 = %d, arg2 = %d", arg1, arg2);
};

void (^doSomething)(int, int) = ^(int arg1, int arg2){
    if (arg1 == 42) {
        // Do something.
    }
};
```

For example, I would like to plug in `logger` in `-(id)init`, but only use `doSomething` while a certain method is running. While `doSomething` is plugged in, `logger` should still run.

**Current implementation**

To maintain the blocks, I thought about using an `NSMutableArray` that stores copies of the blocks and broadcasts the event to all registered blocks (observer pattern).

*- (id)init*

```
self.handlerBlocks = [NSMutableArray array];
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
self.object.handler = ^(int x, int y){
    typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (!strongSelf) {
        return;
    }
    for (void (^item)(int x, int y) in strongSelf.handlerBlocks) {
        item(x, y);
    }
};

[self.handlerBlocks addObject:[self.logger copy]];
```

*- (void)someOtherMethod*

```
void (^doSomething)(int, int) = [^(int arg1, int arg2){
    if (arg1 == 42) {
        // Do something.
    }
} copy];
[self.handlerBlocks addObject:doSomething copy];
// Do something.
[self.handlerBlocks removeObject:doSomething];
```

**Open questions**

Can the method be generalized to blocks with any argument count / types? So that I could use it like this:

```
MulticastBlock *b = [[MulticastBlock alloc] init];
self.object.handler = b;

[b addBlock:self.logger];
```

The problem here is that the type of `self.object.handler` is `void (^)(int, int)`. Therefore, `MulticastBlock` would need to mimic a block, forwarding any invocations it receives to the array.

Could the techniques described here by used?

- https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-10-28-generic-block-proxying.html

Maybe intercepting all invocations, copying them for every array element and assigning new invocation targets?

Comment: What sense does it make to forward an invocation to a block that has a different signature? Or to a list of blocks with varying signatures?

Comment: The blocks share the same signature. However, I would like to reuse the pattern without having to create and the array manually for every callback type.

Imagine that SomeClass has a second handlerblock `void (^otherHandler)(int arg1, NSString *arg2, id arg3)`. With my current approach I would need to double.

The `MulticastBlock` that I listed in the end would match any signature, and could therefore be reused. I'm wondering if such a general block is possible. 

Of course, you would still need to have different instances of the MulticastBlock for every handler, but it's 2 lines instead of 11

Answer (score 1):

From the link you gave to mikeash.com you'll see doing this in code is a challenge, and not something to include in production code. For similar reasons C# stuff works because it is provided by the runtime, you couldn't easily write it yourself in C#. Even parametric polymorphism won't help you here, that won't get you the block call with a varying number of arguments.

What you need is "parametric polymorphism" by string expansion... i.e. macros.

Here is a sample "MulticastBlock.h" file:

```
#define MULTICAST(name, typelist, arglist) \
\
@interface name : NSObject \
\
@property (readonly) void (^block)typelist; \
\
- (id) addBlock:(void (^)typelist)aBlock; \
\
- (void) removeBlock:(id)token; \
\
@end

MULTICAST(MulticastBlock, (int arg1, int arg2), (arg1, arg2))
MULTICAST(MulticastBlock2, (NSString *arg1, NSString *arg2), (arg1, arg2))

#undef MULTICAST
```

This defines a macro which expands out to an `@interface`, uses it twice, then removes the macro as its no longer needed.

The implementation follows your code and is done likewise with a macro - it uses the `arglist` macro argument for the call in the loop, I just include it here for consistency though it isn't used.

The only significant change I made to your code was using an `NSMutableDictionary` with a auto-generated key (just an increasing number) - the key is returned by `addBlock:` and accepted by `removeBlock:` and avoids any issues with blocks being copied (two blocks are only equal if they are the *same* block)

Not exactly what you'd like but it works.

**Addendum**

OK, it wasn't clear how to use this, here is my test code which should explain all:

```
MulticastBlock *multicast = MulticastBlock.new;

id tokenAdd = [multicast addBlock:^(int arg1, int arg2) {
   NSLog(@"%d + %d -> %d", arg1, arg2, arg1 + arg2);
}];

multicast.block(3, 4);

id tokenMul = [multicast addBlock:^(int arg1, int arg2) {
   NSLog(@"%d * %d -> %d", arg1, arg2, arg1 * arg2);
}];

multicast.block(4, 5);

[multicast removeBlock:tokenAdd];

multicast.block(5, 6);

[multicast removeBlock:tokenMul];

multicast.block(6, 7);

MulticastBlock2 *two = MulticastBlock2.new;

[two addBlock:^(NSString *arg1, NSString *arg2) {
   NSLog(@"%@ | %@", arg1, arg2);
}];

two.block(@"asda", @"tesco");
```

Comment: Still, a problem would be to assign the MulticastBlock to the handler ^^, as the handler is of a certain block type, but the MulticastBlock is not a block.

Comment: @Etan - Added my test code to show how it works, you just pass the `block` property as your handler. In your code you assigned direct to the handler, in mine that block is assigned to the property, you then assign the property to the handler in your calling code.